# troubleshooting ansible SSH can't reach a root cause

Tags: ansible

I'm having issues running some playbooks where I define ansible_user_ssh=root in the command line
and the ssh command through ansible, returns permission denied.

```
HOST | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).\r\n",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I'm trying to troubleshoot it and I don't get the root cause.

The keys from root and even the user defined in the inventory (functional users) file are correctly disseminated.
If I do ssh from the root user or functional user, it works no issue in there.

if I execute:

```
ansible -i /app/user/applications/inventory/commercialaseenv300-hosts -m ping -u root HOST
```

It works

If I execute:

```
ansible -i /app/user/applications/inventory/commercialaseenv300-hosts -m ping -e ansible_ssh_user=root HOST
```

**It doesn't work**. Returns permission denied

If I execute:

```
sudo ansible -i /app/user/applications/inventory/commercialaseenv300-hosts -m ping -e ansible_ssh_user=root HOST
```

It works

If I change to root user and execute:

```
ansible -i /app/user/applications/inventory/commercialaseenv300-hosts -m ping -e ansible_ssh_user=root HOST
```

It works

But I need the one that doens't work to work as it is part of a large script.
This was working correctly before and as far as I know, there was no system change.

Could some out of the box eyes give a tip or two.
Thank you in advance

Comment: What version of ansible are you using? Seems `ansible_ssh_user` is deprecated in favor of `ansible_user` in version 2.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the issue was still related with key share. found out that a key has changed (someone ran keygen by mistake)
the keys between the ansible user and root user wasn't correct.

Answer (score 0):

Using `become` could be helpful,

```
$ ansible all -m ping --become-user=root
192.168.1.5 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Need to provide ssh password if you run command/playbook from different user.

```
$ ansible all -m ping -e ansible_ssh_user=root -k
SSH password: 
192.168.1.5 | SUCCESS => {
    "ansible_facts": {
        "discovered_interpreter_python": "/usr/bin/python"
    },
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

Comment: nice, gonna take a note on that.